# restart application as standart user

Tags: java, restart

I writed a java client/server application with a restart function.
On the serverside I added a button to send a reset command to all connected clients.

when I run the client on my computer the restart methode works perfect.

```
public void restartApplication() {
    try {
        final String javaBin = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";
        final File currentJar = new File(Client_Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());

        /* is it a jar file? */
        if (!currentJar.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
            return;
        }

        /* Build command: java -jar application.jar */
        final String command = "\""+javaBin+".exe\" -jar \""+currentJar.getPath()+"\"";

        System.out.println(command);

        final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        builder.start();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client_Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client_Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

My probleme is, all the non-administrator users have a very restriced profile and they can't open the command prompt without administrator priviliges.

Is there any way, how I can restart my jar-file without using command prompt, or run the command promt as administrator?
I can't use the RUNAS  command because I have to enter the admin password the first time, so I have to do that on over 500 computer, that isn't realy an option.

Comment: Double clicking the jar doesn't work?

Comment: @jurgemaister why don't you read the question before commenting unrelated nonsesne comments? how about that? ha ?

Comment: @Yazan Perhaps I didn't understand the question. No need to take that tone. This is actually a Windows question, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is a windows question. When a standart user is logged in, my application has just standart user rights. The command prompt is just for administrator available. so I have to run command prompt  as administrator